# how to Set Android animation on setting new Image Resource

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I have an ImageView in my layout. After clicking a button. I am doing this

```
Image=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById("Imagetag");
Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
```

While I am switching from Image1 to Image2. I want to have an animation to be performed. Anything will do.. Cardflip.FadeIn/Fadeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import:

```
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;

private Animation animFade;

animFade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
```

You can have the onClickListener for the button and add the following code:

```
        animFade.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                       // when fadeout animation ends, fade in your second image
            }
        });
        yourfirstimage.startAnimation(animFade);
```

Create an XML file with the animation in the `res/anim` (fadeout.xml for example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
android:duration="3000" android:repeatCount="0"/>
</set>
```

Hope this code gives you an understanding how animation works. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Note: Always do Animation outside of the UI Thread.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks @SiKni8. Is there any way I can implement the Tile animations done in Windows phone.

Comment: I am sure it is possible but you will have to play around with the idea and try different combination of codes.

Answer (score 1):

add an animation on click to the image view

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); 
fadeIn.setDuration(500);

Image.setAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Comment: Where do I switch to image2 in this code? @bill gates.
Please, Bear with me as I am new to Animations.

Answer (score 1):

try to implement AnimationListener
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html
and just start new animation that's implement your AnimationListener here you can switch images in anymethod